# FFMpeg is dropping video track when clipping an mpg video

Tags: ffmpeg

I am extracting a clip from an mpg video using the following command.
ffmpeg.exe -i 271b.mpg -ss 00:00:05.000 -t 00:00:03.200 -c copy out_271b.mpg

I am using the copy parameter to avoid reencoding the clip.
The resulting mpg file only has the audio track, no video.
The following is the FFMpeg screen dump.

```
C:\ffmpeg-20170615\bin>ffmpeg.exe -i 271b.mpg -ss 00:00:05.000 -t 00:00:03.200 -c copy out_271b.mpg
    ffmpeg version N-86482-gbc40674 Copyright (c) 2000-2017 the FFmpeg developers
      built with gcc 7.1.0 (GCC)
      configuration: --disable-static --enable-shared --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-cuda --enable-cuvid --enable-d3d11va --enable-dxva2 --enable-libmfx --enable-nvenc --enable-avisynth --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenh264 --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib
      libavutil      55. 66.100 / 55. 66.100
      libavcodec     57. 99.100 / 57. 99.100
      libavformat    57. 73.100 / 57. 73.100
      libavdevice    57.  7.100 / 57.  7.100
      libavfilter     6. 92.100 /  6. 92.100
      libswscale      4.  7.101 /  4.  7.101
      libswresample   2.  8.100 /  2.  8.100
      libpostproc    54.  6.100 / 54.  6.100
    Input #0, mpeg, from '271b.mpg':
      Duration: 00:01:11.44, start: 0.460000, bitrate: 2154 kb/s
        Stream #0:0[0x1e0]: Video: mpeg2video (Main), yuv420p(tv, bt470bg, progressive), 640x480 [SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3], 2000 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 90k tbn, 50 tbc
        Stream #0:1[0x1c0]: Audio: mp2, 44100 Hz, mono, s16p, 128 kb/s
    [mpeg @ 0000000000666aa0] VBV buffer size not set, using default size of 130KB
    If you want the mpeg file to be compliant to some specification
    Like DVD, VCD or others, make sure you set the correct buffer size
    Output #0, mpeg, to 'out_271b.mpg':
      Metadata:
        encoder         : Lavf57.73.100
        Stream #0:0: Video: mpeg2video (Main), yuv420p(tv, bt470bg, progressive), 640x480 [SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3], q=2-31, 2000 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 90k tbn, 25 tbc
        Stream #0:1: Audio: mp2, 44100 Hz, mono, s16p, 128 kb/s
    Stream mapping:
      Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
      Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (copy)
    Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
    frame=   74 fps=0.0 q=-1.0 Lsize=     786kB time=00:00:03.17 bitrate=2027.2kbits/s speed= 198x
    video:730kB audio:50kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.843343%
```

Thanks

Addition:  I tried to open the generated clip file with ffplay and got the following results.  Note that ffplay was able to open and play the original mpg file.

```
ffplay.exe out_271b.mpg
ffplay version N-86482-gbc40674 Copyright (c) 2003-2017 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 7.1.0 (GCC)
  configuration: --disable-static --enable-shared --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-cuda --enable-cuvid --enable-d3d11va --enable-dxva2 --enable-libmfx --enable-nvenc --enable-avisynth --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenh264 --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib
  libavutil      55. 66.100 / 55. 66.100
  libavcodec     57. 99.100 / 57. 99.100
  libavformat    57. 73.100 / 57. 73.100
  libavdevice    57.  7.100 / 57.  7.100
  libavfilter     6. 92.100 /  6. 92.100
  libswscale      4.  7.101 /  4.  7.101
  libswresample   2.  8.100 /  2.  8.100
  libpostproc    54.  6.100 / 54.  6.100
[mpeg @ 00000000023cde80] probed stream 2 failedB sq=    0B f=0/0
[mpeg @ 00000000023cde80] start time for stream 0 is not set in estimate_timings_from_pts
[mpeg @ 00000000023cde80] Could not find codec parameters for stream 2 (Video: none, none): unknown codec
Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' and 'probesize' options
Input #0, mpeg, from 'out_271bb.mpg':
  Duration: 00:00:03.22, start: 0.500000, bitrate: 2068 kb/s
    Stream #0:0[0x1bf]: Data: dvd_nav_packet  0KB sq=    0B f=0/0
    Stream #0:1[0x1c0]: Audio: mp2, 44100 Hz, mono, s16p, 128 kb/s
    Stream #0:2[0x1e0]: Video: none, none, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 90k tbn
SDL_OpenAudio (1 channels, 44100 Hz): DirectSoundCreate: No audio device found
No more combinations to try, audio open failed
No codec could be found with id 0
Failed to open file 'out_271b.mpg' or configure filtergraph
```

Comment: Command output shows no errors, only a warning. Add `-f dvd` and check,

Comment: Mulvya.  I retried with the command as follows:
`ffmpeg.exe -i 271b.mpg -ss 00:00:05.000 -t 00:00:03.200 -c copy -f dvd out_271b.mpg`
Same result.

Comment: How are you checking the output? What's the result of `ffplay out_271b.mpg`?

Comment: Mulvya.  I have been using MediaInfo to inspect the internals, an VLC to try to play it.  I have added the dump from FFPlay to the post.  Note that FFPlay was successful in opening the original file.  Thanks